# How to use some filter together with recovery initial object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have array of object `this.fltUsers`.

Below I listen incoming messages and do filtering of `this.fltUsers`.

```
this.filterForm.controls["gender"].valueChanges.subscribe(selectedValue => {
      this.requestLoadPersonal = this.fltUsers.filter((p: Personal) => {
        return selectedValue ? p.gender == selectedValue : true;
      });
    });

    this.filterForm.controls["position"].valueChanges.subscribe(
      selectedValue => {
        this.requestLoadPersonal = this.fltUsers.filter((p: Personal) => {
          return selectedValue ? p.positionId == selectedValue : true;
        });
      }
    );
```

Where `this.requestLoadPersonal` contains filtered data.

How to pass result of first filtering to second? To make condition `AND` between two `filters`?
How to recovery initial object?

Perhaps I can use replacement like:

```
if (this.requestLoadPersonal !== this.fltUsers) {
    // FILTER BY this.requestLoadPersonal
} else {
   // FILTER BY this.fltUsers
}
```

Seems I must to store statement of object every time before change, then I can recovery it to previous statement.

Comment: make filter pipeable to another? Or better yer use filter() that already is pipeable?
eg. var words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present']; var result = words.filter(word => word.length > 3).filter(word => word.length > 7); Notice how words unchanged but result has a piped filter 1 and filter 2 result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using rxjs. If thats the case you can use rxjs Operators.
Maybe have a look at the documentation [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/).

In your case this may do it:

```
const firstCondition = this.filterForm.controls["gender"].valueChanges.pipe(map(selectedValue => {
  this.fltUsers.filter((p: Personal) => p.gender == selectedValue);
}));

const secondCondition = this.filterForm.controls["position"].valueChanges.pipe(map(
  selectedValue => {
    this.fltUsers.filter((p: Personal) => p.positionId == selectedValue);
  }));

merge(firstCondition, secondCondition).pipe(reduce((acc, val) => acc && val), true);
```

I am mapping both observables to your condition (`pipe` and `map`). Then i can use `merge` to create a single observable stream that contains both values and `reduce` it to a single boolean in the end.